# latest compiled files are not taken by Jdeveloper

Tags: java, jdeveloper, oc4j

My application uses stuts and spring framework and we use Jdeveloper and OC4J server.

Yesterday I took the latest workspace and when I compile all the new class files are generated. When I make any changes rebuild and restart Jdev server I don't see my changes in the UI. I checked all the path and looks like it's pointing properly.

What else could you guys think off?

Answer (score 1):

I just had The same Problem, renaming The classes, Files, and whatever was not working, solved the Problem. Sadly this happens pretty often

Comment: i just renamed the class Files, which did not change

Comment: renaming didnt help either. So u couldnt fix it?

Comment: In my case it did work to just rename the files, which did not work.

Comment: oh k. Thank you! I dont know what else can help. it behaves weird.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the clean all option in the build menu.

Answer (score 1):

After performing the clean all, as Shay suggests,  you can delete all '.data' folders. They are normally not cleared by jdev, but are most of the time the reason you see this behavior. 
If the '.data' folders are chills of the classes folder you can just delete the classes folder.